# Computer keeps restarting after installing two extra RAM modules

Tags: memory

I recently purchased two 8GB Kingston hyperx Fury DDR4 2666 RAM sticks. My computer currently has two 8GB RAM sticks that are of the same type. I want to add the extra two RAM sticks so that the total memory is 32GB.

However, when I insert the two extra RAM modules and start up my computer, all it does is restarts and shuts down on a continuos loop with nothing showing on the monitor.

I have tested all four memory slots with a single 8GB RAM and each slot works fine and the computer boots normally.

My PC currently contains the following hardware:

- Gigabyte Z170XP-SLI ATX motherboard
- X2 8GB Kingston Fury DDR4 2666 RAM
- X2 Gigabyte GTX 1070 G1 Gaming GPU's
- i5 6600K 3.5GHz CPU
- 700W Power Supply
- Windows 10

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you boot it with one or two sticks and make sure that the memory is set to 2133MHz (the regular max for your I5 6600K).  Reason behind it that more memory ranks add more load and that things might work fine with fewer DIMMs at a higher speed.  That is assuming you OC the memory or have XMP enabled. If not, could you please add to your original post that no OC is taking place at all?

Comment: With these types of issues a bios update (if available) and a bios reset to default settings is a good first step. The comment about adding the sticks one by one is also good (do the 2 new ones work. How about 3)